# Python: json to json array and append date in the beginning

Tags: python, json

I have this json :

```
[{"UGC_TECH_PLATEFORME": "youtube", "UGC_TECH_ID": "UCu93VC-rD_TolBF4Pe5yz_Q"}]
```

And i'd like to get this one:

```
[{"2020-09-23":{"UGC_TECH_PLATEFORME": "youtube", "UGC_TECH_ID": "UCu93VC-rD_TolBF4Pe5yz_Q"}}]
```

I guess i should use append method but i really don't know nor find how.

Thanks.

Comment: `yourjson[0] = {"2020-09-23":yourjson[0]}`.

Answer (score 2):

@jizhihaoSAMA write answer, if u want save today json:

```
from datetime import datetime

yourjson[0] = {
          str(datetime.now().date()) : yourjson[0]
    }
```